# Return Date To Client From Within DB::Transaction Closure()

Tags: laravel, transactions, laravel-5

I am executing several database saves within my db transaction closure:

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    ...
});
```

However what i want to do now is when a transaction fails instead of throwing an exception i want to return a custom JSON object straight t the client, if the transactions succeeds i want to do the same thing.

This is my object:

```
return [
  'code' => '',
  'message' => '',
  'data' => []
];
```

How would i return the above to the client from within the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of DB::transaction Closure you can use DB::beginTransaction, DB::commit and DB::rollback methods in order to have more control in code, you can wrap your DB actions like this :

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);
    DB::insert(...);

    //If everything is ok we commit
     DB::commit();
     return response()->json(["status" => "success"])
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      //something goes wrong, we rollback
      DB::rollback();
      return response()->json(["error" => "Some error"]);
}
```

You can research more in [database transaction docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#database-transactions)

Comment: Thanks :) that helped.